# How to apply custom LUT with Core Image iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-image

I have a 2D look up table and would like to use to as filter. I have read how to create custom CIFilters, the main part is writing the kernel code and this is where I am stuck.

```
kernel vec4 coreImageKernel(sampler Image, __table sampler LUT) {
  vec4 p = sample(Image, samplerCoord(Image));

  float size = 23.0;

  float x = p.r * (size - 1.0);
  float y = p.g * (size - 1.0) + p.b * (size - 1.0) * size;

  vec4 newPix = sample(LUT, vec2(x, y));

  return vec4(newPix.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

However, this does not give me anything close to correct.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Be specific please. What are you trying to do with your "2D look up table"? Also, please post code you have outside of the kernel, along with specifics as to what results (or errors) you are seeing. Thanks.

Comment: Where you able to figure this out?